# Alter the type of an existing column with TSQL - what about the constraint?

Tags: t-sql, constraints, alter-table

I want to alter the type of a column from bit to tinyint. This is my SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TINYINT NOT NULL
```

This tells me that there is a constraint for column. I dropped the constraint, but is this really necessary? Whats the right way to do this? I think afterwards I need a constraint, too.

Thanks :)

Comment: **Need input!**  What was the constraint?  What was the message?  What version of SQL (I'm assuming SQL Server)?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, The message was that there is a constraint, named *DF__table__column__6FEA6AF6*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes this was necessary.**

A constraint on a `BIT` field can't possibly work on a `tinyint` field since they are different datatypes.

The `BIT` value of `1` doesn't mean "The number one", it indicates `true` or `yes` or `on`.

It's as if you had a rule:

> This value needs to be a date between 1/1/2010 and 12/31/2010

...and then you changed the value to be a decimal datatype.  The decimal can't possibly meet the criteria of the constraint.

Before DDL operations you must disable constraints since they may be invalid after the change.

Comment: So Ill drop it and create it again after the type was changed? No other way?

Comment: @grady - yes.  The old constraint won't even work if it was a `BIT` before and a `TinyInt` afterwards.

Comment: The rationalisation about `true`/`false` seems bogus. You would get the same moving from `tinyint` to `int`. It is just a limitation of the grammar AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinSmith - it is bogus, I'm just trying to make him understand why